# Getting reaction time after pressing a key game

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, key-bindings

So I am making a game that records your reaction time after you see something pop up on the screen, but I am having trouble with getting that reaction time. I want the user to press the up arrow key once they see a blue ball and I want to record their reaction time once they pressed that button.

Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends JPanel 
{

private JLabel start, main, time;
private ImageIcon constant, react;

final int width = 600;
final int height = 600;

private Timer replace;


private Random random;
private int randTime;

private long startTime;
private long stopTime;
private long reactionTime;
private Action upAction;


public Game()
{

  setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  setBackground(Color.black);

  start = new JLabel("Click Up Arrow when you see a blue ball");
  start.setForeground(Color.white);
  start.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
  add(start);
 
  constant = new ImageIcon("constantCircle.png");
  main = new JLabel(constant);
  main.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);


  randomTime();
  replace = new Timer(randTime, timeListener);
  startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  replace.setRepeats(false);
  replace.start();    
  add(main);

  time = new JLabel("0");

  time.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "upAction");
  time.getActionMap().put("upAction", upAction);


  add(time);

}


public void randomTime()
{
  random = new Random();
  int max = 8000;
  randTime = random.nextInt(max);

}


ActionListener timeListener = new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
  {
    react = new ImageIcon("reactCircle.png");
    main.setIcon(react);     
  }
};

public class UpAction extends AbstractAction
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    reactionTime = stopTime - startTime;
    time.setText("" + reactionTime);
  
  }
}  
}
```

I setup a "startTime" using System.currentTimeMillis to get the time after the ball turns blue but I am not sure if that is the correct way to do it.

I also setup a "stopTime" in the "UpAction" class where I want to get the time once the user presses up arrow but I it does not work.

if anything doesn't make sense or isn't clear enough, I'll try my best to elaborate more

Comment: 1) Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. There is no main() method or JFrame. We can't copy/paste/compile and test the posted code. 2) Basic code looks reasonable. However, you need to use the proper `InputMap`. A JLabel doesn't have focus and therefore does not receive key events. As a stated in your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67672782/ending-a-timer-using-keyadapters. `A Key Binding can be configured to receive the KeyEvent even when the panel doesn't have focus.`. So reread the tutorial link you were given and use the appropriate `InputMap`.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following GUI.

[image: Reaction Time Game]

There are two important principles I want to explain.  The first is that creating the GUI is a separate process from updating the GUI.  The second is that the game process is a state machine.  The game is in six separate states.  Here's what I wrote to keep the states in mind.

Sequence of events

1. Left-click button
2. Wait 2 - 4 seconds to display the circle.
3. Capture start time
4. Left-click button
5. Capture end time.
6. Calculate and display reaction time.
7. Repeat 1 - 6.

So, for the GUI, I created a `JFrame` and three `JPanels`; an upper `JPanel`, a drawing `JPanel`, and a button `JPanel`.

I started the Swing application with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

The `JFrame` has a default `BorderLayout`, which I used to place the three `JPanels`.  The `JFrame` method calls must be executed in a specific order.  This is the order I use for all my Swing applications.

The upper `JPanel` contains the instructions and the reaction time display.  A `JTextArea` is great for displaying instructions.  I put the `JTextArea` inside an inner `JPanel` using a `FlowLayout`, which I placed in the upper `JPanel` using a `BorderLayout`.  Nesting layouts like this is a good way to organize the Swing components in a logical manner.

I put the reaction time Swing components in another inner `JPanel`, which I placed in the upper `JPanel`.

I created a drawing `JPanel` so I wouldn't have to bother with an image.

The button `JPanel` holds the Submit `JButton`.

I created two controller classes.  One controller class, `ButtonListener`, responds to the `JButton` left-clicks.  The other controller class, `TimerListener`, creates the delay for drawing the circle.

The `ButtonListener` state variable allows me to provide different functionality with the same `ActionListener`.  If you wish, you can write separate `ActionListener` classes, one for each function.

By separating my code into view and controller classes, I could separate my concerns and focus on one part of the application at a time.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ReactionTimeGame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ReactionTimeGame());
    }
    
    private long reactionTime;
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JTextField reactionTimeField;
    
    public ReactionTimeGame() {
        this.reactionTime = 0L;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Reaction Time Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createUpperPanel(), BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JPanel createUpperPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
        String instructions = "This game will test your reaction time. To play "
                + "the game, left-click on the Submit button.  After a random time "
                + "from 2 - 4 seconds, a circle will appear.  Left-click the "
                + "Submit button again.  Your reaction time will be displayed "
                + "above where the circle was.\n\n"
                + "Left-click the Submit button to start each round of the game.";
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(7, 40);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setText(instructions);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        innerPanel.add(textArea);
        
        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.BEFORE_FIRST_LINE);
        
        innerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Reaction Time:");
        innerPanel.add(label);
        
        reactionTimeField = new JTextField(5);
        reactionTimeField.setEditable(false);
        updateReactionTime();
        innerPanel.add(reactionTimeField);
        
        label = new JLabel("seconds");
        innerPanel.add(label);
        
        panel.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        panel.add(button);
        
        return panel;
    }
    
    public void setReactionTime(long reactionTime) {
        this.reactionTime = reactionTime;
    }

    public void drawCircle() {
        drawingPanel.setDrawCircle(true);
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public void eraseCircle() {
        drawingPanel.setDrawCircle(false);
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public void updateReactionTime() {
        double time = 0.001 * reactionTime;
        reactionTimeField.setText(String.format("%.3f", time));
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private boolean drawCircle;
        
        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.drawCircle = false;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        }

        public void setDrawCircle(boolean drawCircle) {
            this.drawCircle = drawCircle;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            if (drawCircle) {
                int centerX = getWidth() / 2;
                int centerY = getHeight() / 2;
                int radius = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) * 9 / 20;
                int diameter = radius + radius;
                g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                g.fillOval(centerX - radius, centerY - radius, diameter, diameter);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private int state;
        
        private long startTime;
        
        private final Random random;
        
        private Timer timer;
        
        public ButtonListener() {
            this.state = 1;
            this.random = new Random();
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            switch (state) {
            case 1:
                int delay = random.nextInt(2000) + 2000;
                timer = new Timer(delay, new TimerListener(this));
                timer.start();
                state = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                setEndTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                eraseCircle();
                state = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        public int getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public void setStartTime(long startTime) {
            this.startTime = startTime;
        }

        public void setEndTime(long endTime) {
            long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
            setReactionTime(elapsedTime);
            updateReactionTime();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        
        private final ButtonListener listener;

        public TimerListener(ButtonListener listener) {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            Timer timer = (Timer) event.getSource();
            timer.stop();
            
            if (listener.getState() == 2) {
                listener.setStartTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
                drawCircle();
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: The Ops requirement was: *I want the user to press the up arrow key once they see a blue ball*. How does this solve the OP's problem of responding to a KeyEvent?

Comment: @camickr: The OP can replace a button press with a key press.  The point of this answer was to show the OP how to separate creating a GUI from updating a GUI and the states involved in creating a game like this.

Comment: *The OP can replace a button press with a key press* - No the OP can't which is the reason why the question was asked. I'm still waiting for the OP to post a proper MRE so we can help with the key bindings.